# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: freemarker/template/TemplateModelException

Tags: selenium, freemarker

Tried to create advanced `HTML` reports using `extentReports` jar, but it is throwing below error.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   freemarker/template/TemplateModelException

Code:

```
public class XtentReport { 
   WebDriver driver; 
   ExtentReports report; 
   ExtentTest logger; 

@Test public void verifyXReport() { 
   report = new ExtentReports("D:\\Selenium_Reports\\AdvanceReport.html"); 
   logger=report.startTest("StartingTC"); driver= new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.manage().window().maximize(); logger.log(LogStatus.INFO,"Browser is up and running"); 
   driver.get("google.com"); 
   logger.log(LogStatus.PASS,"Test completed"); report.endTest(logger); 
   report.flush(); 
   } 
 }
```

Comment: you need to provide related jar to project classpath...

Comment: You need to use the Freemaker Jar or Freemarker dependency in case you are using any build tool like Maven or Gradle, Use the below link to download the jar or take the dependency refrence. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker

Answer (score 7):

**Maven:**
If maven is used as a build tool then just add the below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.23</version>
</dependency>
```

**No Maven:**
If maven is not used, add the below jar to the classpath.

Download freemarker-2.3.23.jar from the below link.
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.23/freemarker-2.3.23.jar

If a different version is needed then use the below link and choose the version needed.
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/freemarker/freemarker

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `freemarker-<version>.jar` to yor classpath.

Comment: Added freemarker-2.3.20.jar to classpath but now its throwing,             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: freemarker/template/TemplateModelException                                                Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: freemarker/ext/beans/BeansWrapperBuilder
 at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.HTMLReporter.start(HTMLReporter.java:76)
 at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.Report.attach(Report.java:314)
 at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.<init>(ExtentReports.java:85)

Comment: @ChaluvarajuPs can you Show how you add it to classpath?

Comment: added jar version freemarker-2.3.23.jar, its working fine now. thanks much

Answer (score 1):

If someone came here because have this same error using [XDocReport](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport), pay attention: it's just a `WARN` :).

Comment: exacly, I had same issue. If you are only using velocity with XdocReport, you don't need the freemarker dependency. This warning can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You  downloading the apache freemarker 2.3.30 jar available at the [below link](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/freemarker/engine/2.3.30/binaries/apache-freemarker-2.3.30-bin.tar.gz):