# HTML file is not getting created - Extent Report (Junit)

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber-java, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I need to create a report using Extent Report and Junit, I developed the follow code, but when I run it, the HTML file (Report) is not getting created.

```
public class Steps extends Execute {
    private static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
    private static ExtentReports extentReport;
    private static ExtentTest extentTest;

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeCenario(Scenario cenario) {
    if(extentReport == null) {
        extentReport = new ExtentReports();
        htmlReporter = new 
        ExtentHtmlReporter("src/test/resources/htmlReporter.html");

        extentReport.attachReporter(htmlReporter);  
    }

        extentTest = extentReport.createTest(cenario.getId());

    }

    @Test
    @Given("acessei a url do portal")
    public void AcessoUrl() {
           Execute Executar = new Execute();
           Executar.abrirBrowser();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterCenario(Scenario cenario) {
        extentTest.log(Status.PASS, "Cenario "+ cenario.getName()+ "executado com sucesso!");
        extentReport.flush();
    }
```

I have tried `@Before`, but It's not run my code, I have received this message:

> Failure in before hook:Steps.beforeCenario(Scenario)
>   Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: freemarker/template/TemplateModelException

The freemarker dependency is on my pom.XML:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.23</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried `@BeforeTest` too, It run my code, but it also is not creating the HTML file.

Can you help me, please? Thanks =)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221933/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-freemarker-template-templatemodelexception

Comment: @user7294900 Thanks, but I've already tried it =( The freemarker.jar is on my pom.xml

Comment: If you are using extentreports-4.0, then the easiest possible way is to use the TestNG adapter provided by the framework itself:  http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/testng.html.

Comment: The above adapter Anshoo had mentioned should also work with version 3.